# Jquery plugin datatables disapears after filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using Jquery plugin datatables to sort information in my tables, but after I use custom made filter for table the data table plugin disapears.

Here is a code of my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loans_table').DataTable( {
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'l>>" + 
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + 
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'p>>",
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "previous": "&lt;",
                "next": "&gt;"
            },
            "lengthMenu": '<select>'+
                '<option value="-1">{{ 'text.show_all'|trans }}</option>'+
                '<option value="10">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 10</option>'+
                '<option value="25">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 25</option>'+
                '<option value="50">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 50</option>'+
                '</select>',
        },
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets" : 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
        }],
        "bDestroy" : true,
     } );
} );
```

And here is the code for filter:

```
$('#filter-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
      var value = this.value;
      if (value && (!$.isNumeric(value) || value < 0) ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
        console.log(value);
        valid = false;
      } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });
    if (valid) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('app_filter'), // call ApplicationController:filterAction()
        data: $(this).serialize(), // send form data
        //dataType: 'json', // what data accept, html?
        timeout: 60000, // how long to wait for response
        success: function(response) {
          $('#ajax-update').html(response); // insert response data into table
          knp.init(options);
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#match').text('Problem!'); // smth to show if error
        }
      });
    }
 });
```

Has anyone came across to any similar problem?

Comment: Please demonstrate your problem on an example.

Comment: create a fiddle to explain issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by writing table = before $('#loans_table').DataTable( {

And by clearing, deleting table and reinitialising it again. This is how it looks like:

```
$('#filter-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid = true;
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
      var value = this.value;
      if (value && (!$.isNumeric(value) || value < 0) ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
        console.log(value);
        valid = false;
      } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
      }
    });
    if (valid) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('app_filter'), // call ApplicationController:filterAction()
        data: $(this).serialize(), // send form data
        //dataType: 'json', // what data accept, html?
        timeout: 60000, // how long to wait for response
        success: function(response) {
        $('#ajax-update').html(response); // insert response data into table
        knp.init(options);
        if (table) table.clear();

        //reinitialise the dataTable   
        table = $('#loans_table').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'l>>" + 
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + 
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'p>>",
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "previous": "&lt;",
                "next": "&gt;"
            },
            "lengthMenu": '<select>'+
                '<option value="-1">{{ 'text.show_all'|trans }}</option>'+
                '<option value="10">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 10</option>'+
                '<option value="25">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 25</option>'+
                '<option value="50">{{ 'text.show'|trans }} 50</option>'+
                '</select>',
        },
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets" : 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
        }]
        });
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#match').text('Problem!'); // smth to show if error
        }
      });
    }
    $(this).find('[type=submit]').blur();
  });
```